# Exact time of looking for dependency in Java

Tags: java, jar, dependencies

When exactly Java looks for dependencies of a Jar file at Run Time?

At the very beginning of running it?
When it tries to Initialize a Class which has some dependency?
Or any other time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Java Language Specification, §12.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#44487) says (my emphasis):

> This specification allows an implementation flexibility as to when linking activities (**and, because of recursion, loading**) take place, provided that the semantics of the language are respected, that a class or interface is completely verified and prepared before it is initialized, and that errors detected during linkage are thrown at a point in the program where some action is taken by the program that might require linkage to the class or interface involved in the error.
>
> For example, an implementation may choose to resolve each symbolic reference in a class or interface individually, only when it is used (lazy or late resolution), or to resolve them all at once while the class is being verified (static resolution). This means that the resolution process may continue, in some implementations, after a class or interface has been initialized.

Now, the specification says that a JVM *can* do a range of things, but clearly, any given JVM *does* do one particular thing. Marko's answer says that "all class files in the classpath may be loaded even before the `main` method starts executing", and he's right, but the fact is that no JVM actually does that.

I believe that what actually happens in the Sun JVM is that things are loaded as late as possible. Whenever a class is initialized, then any classes it refers to need to be loaded and verified, but they don't need to be initialized until they themselves are actually used. I appreciate that this is not a very detailed or authoritative answer.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly when a .class file will be loaded is not specified. For all you know, all class files in the classpath may be loaded even before the `main` method starts executing.

The only thing that Java specifies is when a class will be **initialized**, which is an entirely different thing from loading it.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure it happens at compilation time. You won't get compiled version of your code without meeting all requirements and dependencies.

In case of compiled jar, I've prepared two classes:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("T1: Hello world");
    Test2.greet();
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void greet() {
        System.out.println("T2: Hello world");
    }
}
```

First attempt of running an exported project:

```
$ java -jar test.jar
T1: Hello world
T2: Hello world
```

Then, after removal Test2.class from my jar file and then running it again:

```
$ java -jar test-mod.jar
T1: Hello world
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test2
        at Test.main(Test.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Test2
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

T1 test passed, then NoClassDefFoundError exception appeared. So, answering to your question: dependencies will be checked at run-time.

Comment: Obviously, this is not my answer! It requires all the dependencies at the compile time but I'm talking about run time. Consider a "copied version" of a Jar file.

Comment: Ok, I assumed it's as easy as it sounds ;) I'll add new answer soon.